# Django rest framework request handling

Tags: django, multithreading, django-rest-framework

How does Django rest framework handles request ? Is it process based or it thread model. 
For each request does one process start a new thread or its just one process which takes care of all request (like it happens in NodeJS) based on context.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about Django and not DRF. That said, I believe Django is single-threaded, but thread-safe. You might want to have a look to Celery if you are interested in deferred tasks.